# Kubernetes: Deploy applications to blue and green node groups

Tags: kubernetes

My eks vpc has two node groups. One is named blue, another is named green. Each node group provisioned (terraform) by using resource "aws_eks_node_group" with scaling_config, i.e. each node group is ASG enabled. I would like to deploy scs_1.0 release to blue node group, deploy csc_1.1 release to green node group. How to do that?

In the past, I use resource "aws_eks_node_group" (terraform) provision eks worker nodes (one node group), then logon to the Kubernetes cluster, deploy application there. Now, I use resource "aws_eks_node_group" provisioned two node groups. How do I deploy different releases to different node groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to deploy diffrent 'deployment' to different node. So, you can use `nodeSelector` on `Deployment` to select labels of node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx-v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx-v1
  replicas: 1

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxx-v1
        type: microservice
    

    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        nodeGroup: blue
      containers:
      - name: xxx-v1
        image: xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx-v1-sandbox
....
```

You can assign label to node by `kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>`